# Properties regarding Poisson non-integrability

Tags: integration

Let $a>0$ and $f:[a,\infty]\to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous increasing function. We call $f$ to be "Poisson non-integrable" if $f$ satisfies
$$\int_a^\infty \frac{f(x)}{x^2}dx=\infty.$$
Now define $g:[a,\infty]\to [0,\infty)$ by
$$g(x)=\int_a^x\frac{f(s)}{s} ds.$$

Questions:

1. Does $f$ "Poisson non-integrable" implies $g$ is also "Poisson non-integrable"?
2. Is the converse of 1. true?

Comment: This is not the right site for your question; please try https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: As for the question, the answer is yes, because a calculation using Fubini shows that $\int g/x^2\, dx = \int f/x^2\, dx$.

Comment: Thank you Christian.